Access denied when using rpdupload
I am using Oracle BI Analytics 12.2.1.3.0 on OL 8.9.
I use the command:
/home/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/mydomain/bitools/bin/datamodel.sh uploadrpd -I myrpd.rpd -SI ssi -U rpdupload -P <rpduserpwd> -W <rpdpwd>
This gives me an error: "Connection failed, the server processes may be down"
Checking bi-lcm-rest.log.0 shows that the response returned was "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException : HTTP 401 Unauthorized","oracle.bi.restkit.security.auth.RequiredGroupAuthoriser"
If I add the "rpdupload" user into the Administrators group, the command works. However, this introduces a security weakness and I want this to be a restricted user.
I tried other groups, such as Deployers, but that didn't work.

Several things:
1.) All functionality is governed by Application Policies
2.) Application Policies are tied to Application Roles for authorization purposes
3.) Randomly changing "groups" (which are not the same thing as Application Roles) will not solve your issue
4.) The Application Policy for managing RPDs is by default only granted to the BI Service Administrator Application Role
5.) Nothing is stopping you from creating a new customer Application Role with the required functional Application Policies granted and to which you then assign your rpduploaduser
The platform supports this all very easily it just needs to be utilized according to suitable rules and standards. Plan your security properly and think about what should work how.

Can you kindly explain? At first, I had assigned the rpduload user to the group "BI Service Administrator" but kept getting permission denied message. That is when I tried other groups. As I said, that method was not satisfactory which is why I asked in the post what the correct method is. Yes, I know the difference between roles and groups. I have mapped the BI Service Admin policy to the BI Service Group. I also tried putting the user directly into the policy. Didn't work for me.
